# What are the logging capabilities of vbs?

Tags: logging, vbscript

I currently have an `.vbs`, and what it does is, it converts a `.xls` file to `.csv`. But, I want to know what it is doing in the back-end, and save that to a `.log` file.

I know that in batch scripts you can use `>> xls-to-vbs.log`. I'm looking for something similar for my`vbs` file?

> What are the logging capabilities of vbs?

Comment: Can you post your code ?

Comment: @Hackoo, the question mentioned above, helped me so far. So, pointless to post. Thanks for looking in to this!